# julia alternative for np.recarray/tables

Tags: julia

Is there an analogue to [`np.recarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html)? `np.recarray` handles columns of different number formats and allows row-wise slicing. In julia I only managed to get vector of vectors and unions.

Comment: The original source format of the data matters. Are you importing the record array into recarray form in NumPy with records.fromrecords? If so, you may want to use TableIO or DataFrames to import the data in Julia. If the records are generated internally, a vector of named tuples might be enough.

Answer (score 4):

It is difficult to know which one would be best suited for your needs.

I think the closest match would be [StructArrays.jl](https://juliaarrays.github.io/StructArrays.jl/stable/) but maybe you want to go toward [IndexedTables.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/IndexedTables.jl) or use [DataFrames.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl).

Keep in mind that [DataFrames.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl) is the most popular one, with less overhead than the Python alternative. I think without more information I would pick this one.